# How to find Spark RDD created in different cores of a computer

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython

I just wanted to educate myself more on Spark. So wanted to ask this question.

I have Spark currently installed on my local machine. Its a Mach with 16GB.

I have connected a Jupyter notebook running with Pyspark.

So now when I do any coding in that notebook, like reading the data and converting the data into Spark DataFrame, I wanted to check:

1). Where all the dataset is distributed on local machine. Like does it distribute the dataset using different cores of CPU etc?. Is there a way to find that out?

2). Running the code and computation just using Jupyter notebook without spark is different from running Jupyter notebook with Pyspark? Like the first one just uses one core of the machine and runs using one thread while Jupyter notebook with Pyspark runs the code and computing on different cores of CPU with multi-threading/processing? Is this understanding correct?.

Is there a way to check these.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter has mainly three parts Jupyter Notebook, Jupyter Clients and Kernels.  http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/how_jupyter_ipython_work.html

*Here is short note on Kernel from Jupyter homepage.*

> Kernels are processes that run interactive code in a particular
>   programming language and return output to the user. Kernels also
>   respond to tab completion and introspection requests.

Jupyter's job is to communicate between the Kernel(Like python kernel, spark kernel ..) and web interface(your notebook). So under the hood spark is running drivers and executors for you, Jupyter helps in communicating with the spark driver.

> 1). Where all the dataset is distributed on local machine. Like does
>   it distribute the dataset using different cores of CPU etc?. Is there
>   a way to find that out?

Spark will spawn n number of executors(process responsible for executing a task) as specified using `--num-executors`, executors are managed by a spark driver(program/process responsible for running the Job over the Spark Engine). So the number of executors are specified while you run a spark program, you will find this kernel conf directory.

> 2). Running the code and computation just using Jupyter notebook
>   without spark is different from running Jupyter notebook with Pyspark?
>   Like the first one just uses one core of the machine and runs using
>   one thread while Jupyter notebook with Pyspark runs the code and
>   computing on different cores of CPU with multi-threading/processing?
>   Is this understanding correct?.

Yes, as I explained Jupyter is merely an interface letting you run code. Under the hood, Jupyter connects to Kernels be it normal Python or Apache Spark.

Spark has it's own good UI to monitor jobs, by default it runs on spark master server on port 4040. In your case, it will available on http://localhost:4040

Comment: So just to understand,whenever I open a Jupyter notebook using Pyspark, I am using Spark Kernel and hence even if I run the code on local mac, it still uses distributed computing unlike just python notebook?

Secondly, even If I am using Spark kernel but until and unless I use the Spark RDD or Spark DataFrames the distributed computing won't happen right?. Like I can use Pandas DataFrame in Spark too. But that would not distribute the dataset to different executors until it is converted to Spark DataFrame. is that correct?

Comment: Distributed computing as in it will use more than one core if you configure it that way --master local[*] will make use of all the cores. 

Second question - Please try to learn Spark, seems like you are missing on Spark basics.